# How to enable IPv6 on Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, mac, ipv6

I'm using `Yosemite 10.10.3`

```
Wi-Fi BUFFALO
```

Going to `[http://test-ipv6.com/][1]` shows me that "`No IPv6 address detected`"

[image]

Right now its on "`Automatically`"

[image]

If I change it to "`Manual`" - what should I write there? what IPv6 address and Prefix?

+++UPDATE+++

Thanks to @Ramhound I check my ISP and I changed some settings here:

[image]

And I get this:

[image]

So it looks like I have IPv6 now, but still getting message "`No IPv6 address detected`" on this site http://test-ipv6.com/

+++UPDATE2+++

[image]

Comment: If you are going to set it to Manual, you have to configure what the address will be, we can't tell you that.  Are you 100% your ISP even assigns you a IPv6 address?  Based on your screenshots it does not even look like you have a router that is attempting to assign a IPv6 address.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your response. Probably, you're right, I'll ask them.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your router was assigned an IPv6 address.  That does not mean it supports assigning IPv6 addresses itself.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, I'm a nub at this, what should I check? My router doesn't support IPv6? thank you )

Comment: You do understand this website is primarly English.  So a screenshot(s) of an interface most everyone can't read is difficult.  Which is the reason I am phrasing my comments the way I am.

Comment: @Ramhound  Yes, sorry for that, I updated my question. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do a manual configuration.

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu ().
2. Click the Network icon in the System Preferences window.
3. Choose the network service you want to use with IPv6, such as Ethernet or AirPort.
4. Click Advanced, then click TCP/IP.
5. Choose "Manually" from the Configure IPv6 pop-up menu.

enter your IPv6 address, router address, and prefix length,If you don't know these, contact your ISP